# Searching devices using bluetooth in python 2.7

Tags: python

```
import bluetooth

print("performing inquiry...")

nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(lookup_names = True)

print("found %d devices" % len(nearby_devices))

for addr, name in nearby_devices:
print("  %s - %s" % (addr, name))
```

I'm beginner in this language and I got this error message :
 `runfile('C:/Users/Welcome/.xy/startups/one.py',wdir=r'C:/Users/Welcome/.xy/startups'`

Please help me out.

Comment: You need to do correct indentatiton. After for loop print command must be tabbed

Answer (score 0):

As @Ozan Dniz commented, you ought @Karikeswar Das correct the last line's indentation.

```
for addr, name in nearby_devices:
    print("  %s - %s" % ( addr, name ) )  # indented lines "belong" to loop
```

Your code shall use pure <kbd>SPACE</kbd> characters for indentation, not any <kbd>Tab</kbd>-s or mixing 'em together